# 画面固定時のスクロール、スワイプ量の取得

Tags: javascript

例えばコンテントのサイズが
width: 100vw；
height: 100vh；
の時（スクロール不可）にスクロールの上下やスワイプの左右を判定するこは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Firefoxでのみ確認しましたが、今時のブラウザであれば`wheel`イベント（[WheelEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent)）でスクロール量を取得できると思います。

`deltaMode`はスクロールがピクセル単位(0)、行単位(1)、ページ単位(2)なのかを示しますが、ユーザーのスクロール・スワイプ量を知りたいのであれば無視して大丈夫だと思います。

```js
dsip = document.getElementById('disp');
let x=0,y=0,z=0;
document.addEventListener('wheel',(e)=>{
  x += e.deltaX;
  y += e.deltaY;
  z += e.deltaZ;
  
  disp.innerHTML = 
    'x:' + e.deltaX + '<br>' +
    'y:' + e.deltaY + '<br>' +
    'z:' + e.deltaZ + '<br>' +
    '合算' + '<br>' +
    'x:' + x + '<br>' +
    'y:' + y + '<br>' +
    'z:' + z + '<br>' +
    'scroll mode:' + e.deltaMode;
},false);
```

```css
body {
height: 1vw;
width: 1vw;
overflow: hidden;
}

#disp {
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 30px;
}
```

```html
1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>

<div id=disp>disp</div>
```